# Cakephp Special Character Validation

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to to set validation rule in model for user enter only special character only into text field .so please suggest me proper solution.

demo code is

```
public function addValidations()
    {
        parent::addValidations();
        $this->validate['Field name'] = array
        (
            'notempty' => array
            (
                'rule'    => array('special char', 'msg',),
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'message' => 'Enter Special character only.',
            ),
        );
    }
```

Comment: What makes a character *special*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define [Custom Regular Expression Validation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-regular-expression-validation)

```
public $validate = array(
    'login' => array(
        'rule'    => '/^[\W]+$/',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Enter Special character only.'
    )
)
// '/^[\w.-]+$/' this will allow only special character.
```

Comment: public function addValidations() {
  parent::addValidations();
   $this->validate['SeriesConcateCharacter'] = array(
      'SeriesConcateCharacter' => array(
          'rule'    => '/^[\w]+$/',
          'allowEmpty' => false,
          'message' => 'Enter Special character only.'
      )
  );
    }

Comment: SeriesConcateCharacter is field name.

Comment: @Abhishek there was a typo "w written instead of W " .